# Protected general and admin settings in GeoODK app

Tags: data, android, data-collection

I was wondering how to prevent the user to change the general and admin settings of the GeoODK (android-collect)? I mean to be protected with a password, for example.

I've tried to go to **settings** > **admin settings** > and unchecked whatever the user shouldn't access in the **general settings** tab, but still the "**admin setting**" tab is available and the user can get in there and modify anything!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the admin settings by doing those changes :

- decompile you apk by using tools like "apk Icon Editor"
- go to the decompiled temp folder on "C:\Users[your account]\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-icon-editor"
- choose your default admin options once as you want in "C:\Users[your account]\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-icon-editor\apk\res\xml\admin_preferences.xml" by setting each "android:defaultValue"
- once you set your admin options go to "C:\Users[your account]\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-icon-editor\apk\res\values\arrays.xml" and delete the "admin settings" line form the "main-settings" noeud

      Form Management
      General Settings
- in the end you should recompile your apk

Comment: Other questions please, 
1. Could I protect the "Delete data" button using a password? I don't want anyone to be able to delete the data?
2. Could I change the colors "theme" of the forms? 

I tried to play around with the layout .xml files, but I faild :(